# Selenium does not recognize elements after I do zoom out for any % although my xpaths are correct

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, sapui5

Selenium does not recognize elements after I do zoom out for any % although my xpaths are correct and I am able to cross check through inspector tool manually but it doesn't work while running through automation.
Below the stack which I am using
Selenium 4.12,
java 17,
TestNG 7.7,
Maven  4.4

Editor : Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) - Build id: 20211202-1639

This is a table like control from SAP ui5, we are required to sort the 1st and 2nd column values through  automation, but when values are more, selenium only fetches the values which are in the view of the screen, and when we sort through automation, it doesn't match the values because after sorting other values appears on the screen which were not in the view earlier.

Now there is a side vertical scroll bar appears too when values are more, but scroll function too doesn't work.

[image]

**zoom out function **

```
         public void zoomOutPage(int zoomPercentage) throws InterruptedException {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='"+zoomPercentage +"%'");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
     }
```

**Scroll function **

```
    public void scrollToElement(WebElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }
```

Selenium doesn't recognize the element at all.

I tried with explicit waits for condition visibility, presence of element, clickable as well but no luck.

I tried other options as well of scroll as well but those also did not work.  any lead would be a great help.